# convert multidimensional array to string in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
Array ( [0] => LOWER CERVICAL ) 
Array ( [0] => LOWER CERVICAL [1] => Degenerative ) 
Array ( [0] => LOWER CERVICAL [1] => Degenerative [2] => Degenerative )  
Array ( [0] => LOWER CERVICAL [1] => Degenerative [2] => Degenerative [3] => Cervical myelopathy(Spondylotic) )
```

I'm using array to save the result but I don't know how to convert the above array format to the below string format. I have to convert the above array format to String as given in the expected output

Expeceted Output :

```
 LOWER CERVICAL>>Degenerative>>Degenerative>>Cervical myelopathy(Spondylotic)>>
```

Code :

```
while($rsdiag=mysql_fetch_array($sqldiag))
{
    $items[$i] = $rsdiag['di_name'];
    echo $rsdiag['di_name'].">>";
    print_r($items);
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: What you have tried so far? Post your attempts too

Comment: Is this 1 array or is this printed in a loop?

Comment: `echo implode(">>", $items) . ">>";`

Comment: If its a single array then you can simply use `implode('>>',$array[3]).">>";`

Comment: can you show us exactly what do you have as Array.. 
The one you showed is not understandable (do you have 4 rols 1 by 1 for inner levels or you have only the final (last row..) or other..

Comment: if we use echo implode(">>", $items) . ">>" 
 Output is like  LOWER CERVICAL>>LOWER CERVICAL>>Degenerative>>LOWER CERVICAL>>Degenerative>>Degenerative>>LOWER CERVICAL>>Degenerative>>Degenerative>>Cervical myelopathy(Spondylotic)>>LOWER CERVICAL>>Degenerative>>Degenerative>>Cervical myelopathy(Spondylotic)>>

Comment: @Svetlio  $sqldiag=$conn->query("select di_name from assi_diagnosis where di_id IN ($disp1$j)");
      $items = array();
    $i = 0;
     while($rsdiag=mysql_fetch_array($sqldiag))
     {
     $items[$i] = $rsdiag['di_name'];
  echo $rsdiag['di_name'].">>";
  echo implode(">>", $items) . ">>";      
//        print_r($items);
        $i++;
        }

Comment: In your case the solution need some mapping ok ..

Answer (score 0):

I want to notice that this can be not very good but here is some solution which I can suggest only if you dont have big amount of data to be proceeded:

```
rsort($array);
$map = array();

// $array is your strings array
foreach($array as $item) {
  if( empty($map)){
    // First element catch the express..
    $map[] = $item;
    continue;
  }
  $notFound = TRUE;
  foreach($map as $mapItem){
    if( array_intersect_assoc($item, $mapItem) == $item){
      $notFound = FALSE;
    }
  }
  if( $notFound === TRUE) {
    $map[] = $item;
  }
}
foreach($map as $item){
  echo implode(" >> ",$item);
}
```